# Name for a particular family of distributions on unit simplex

Tags: distributions, terminology, entropy

Let $\Delta^n$ be the unit simplex, and let $\alpha\ge 0$ be a parameter. Is there a standard name for the following probability density function supported on $\Delta^n$?
$$f_{\alpha}(p)=C(\alpha)e^{-\alpha H(p)}$$

Here, $H(p)=-\sum_i p_i \log(p_i)$ is the entropy of $p\in\Delta^n$, and $C(\alpha)$ is the normalizing constant.

Comment: Your formula gives a constant density, whence (trivially) this is the uniform distribution, aka Dirichlet$(1,1,\ldots,1)$ distribution. Moreover, $f$ doesn't depend on either $\alpha$ or $p.$  Because I suspect you meant to ask something less trivial, I have closed the question with a request for more information (so that it doesn't collect useless answers in the meantime).

Comment: @whuber, I have edited the post in an attempt to make the definition clearer

Comment: Thank you: I see now what you are trying to do.